# Selectively Deploy Feature Branches on Netlify

Tags: bitbucket, continuous-deployment, netlify, feature-branch

Following our process on BitBucket, we always create a feature branch named `feature/JIRA-23-lost-password` (`JIRA-23-lost-password` being just an example) from which we create several other branches per sub-task.

I would like netlify to automatically deploy all branches that are named `feature/*` but not all the ones that branch from the feature branch.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work at Netlify.

This type of fine grained control doesn't exist currently. The options which are available at this time are:

- only deploy the production branch you select (one branch only - it doesn't have to be `master`)
- automatically deploy all branches
- only deploy branches you select

It sounds like you are looking for a fourth option (one which doesn't exist at this time). We have an open feature request for more fine grained control of which branches are deployed and we'll follow-up here if/when this feature gets added to our service.

Comment: Hi @Luke Lawson, any updates? What's Netlify's recommendation for tags or releases then? i.e. release/v1.0.1 or tag/v1.0.1?