# How to Deploy Specific Branch in Netlify?

Tags: netlify

I'd like to know if there is a way to deploy specific branches in Netlify nowadays? I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891182/selectively-deploy-feature-branches-on-netlify) last year, but really hoping this has been resolved or has a workaround.

Such capability would be very useful for use cases such as deploying the latest staging version (i.e. release/v1.2) or production version from tags (i.e., tags/v1.5). I'm able to filter these dynamic branches in github actions, but don't know how to proceed with Netlify's.

Comment: Why the downvote without any explanation? I already figured this out and been using since then. It involves disabling auto-deploy in Netlify and script the workflow via github actions. The reference that helped me did not come from stackoverflow. I'll try to detail the answer here soon for others to refer to.

Comment: That's great but you're not really sharing you solution that might benefit others.

Answer (score -3):

Try looking on this site:

https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/create-deploys/

There are also on this page some videos on youtube which explain very well

Comment: Did not help. But I already figured it out.

Comment: @dudeuwe what did you do to figure it out?